# Plot multiple timeseries using data in an environment on same graph

Tags: r, quantmod

I am working with the following characters:

```
myTixsectors <- c("APD", "ALB", "AVY", "BLL", "CF", "DWDP", "EMN", "ECL", "FMC", 
"FCX", "IP", "IFF", "LYB", "MLM", "MOS", "NEM", "NUE", "PKG", 
"PPG", "PX", "SEE", "SHW", "VMC", "WRK")
```

and I have the following code to download financial data:

```
data <- new.env()

library(quantmod)

getSymbols(myTixsectors, src = 'yahoo', from = "2018-01-01", to = "2018-06-01", env = data)

normalise_series <- function(xdat) xdat / coredata(xdat)[1]
window <- "2018/"
getSymbols("SPY")

mytheme <- chart_theme()
mytheme$col$line.col <- "blue"
chart_Series(normalise_series(Cl(SPY)[window]) - 1, theme = mytheme, col = "blue")
```

What I am trying to do is to plot the timeseries over the SPY500. I can do it using the following;

```
mytheme <- chart_theme()
mytheme$col$line.col <- "blue"
chart_Series(normalise_series(Cl(SPY)[window]) - 1, theme = mytheme, col = "blue")
add_TA(normalise_series(Cl(data$ALB)[window]) - 1, on = 1, col = "red", lty = 3)
add_TA(normalise_series(Cl(data$AVY)[window]) - 1, on = 1, col = "red", lty = 3)
add_TA(normalise_series(Cl(data$BLL)[window]) - 1, on = 1, col = "red", lty = 3)
add_TA(normalise_series(Cl(data$CF)[window]) - 1, on = 1, col = "red", lty = 3)
add_TA(normalise_series(Cl(data$DWDP)[window]) - 1, on = 1, col = "red", lty = 3)
```

However this is more time consuming and I cannot repeat it onto new data because each time I would manually have to change `data$DWDP`, `data$CF` etc.

I have tried to create a for loop in order to add the time series;

```
for(tick in myTixsectors){
  add_TA(normalise_series(Cl(data[[tick]])[window]) - 1, on = 1, col = "yellow", lty = 3)
}
```

However this does not work. Is there a way to call all dataframes in an environment and plot them?

Note: this is a follow up question relating to an earlier question I posted [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51223719/merging-columns-from-different-dataframes-with-unique-names). The objective is similar, however I feel this is more of a correct way to tackle the problem.

EDIT: I am also trying `eapply` with no luck.

```
eapply(data, function(x) add_TA(normalise_series(Cl(x))))
```

Answer (score 0):

To answer my own question, I used the following:

```
mytheme <- chart_theme()
mytheme$col$line.col <- "blue"
chart_Series(ROC(Cl(SPY))[window], theme = mytheme, col = "blue")
eapply(data, function(x) add_TA(ROC(Cl(x))[window], on = 1, col = "grey", lty = 3))
```

Which plots the returns of the closing prices for all the symbols in the list, using the `eapply` function with the SPY returns plotted in blue.